Inequality for complex numbers.
I have this result I would like to prove.

Let $c_1, c_2$ be complex numbers. Let $n$ be a natural number bigger
than zero. Then we have
$$|c_1^n-c_2^n|\le |c_1-c_2|\cdot n\cdot \max(|c_1|,|c_2|)^{n-1}.$$

Do you see how to prove this?
Attempt:
I am able to show the result for real numbers $r_1,r_2$ and $n=2$, because then we can use $r_1^2-r_2^2=(r_1-r_2)(r_1+r_2)$. So we get
$$|r_1^2-r_2^2|=|r_1-r_2||r_1+r_2|\le|r_1-r_2|\cdot2\cdot\max(|r_1|,|r_2|).$$

@YvesDaoust Sorry, it was a typo.

Hint: similar to grade $2$, there is a general identity
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\cdot(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots + ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$
can you finish the proof from here?

Yes, thank you very much. I'll try to prove the identity you have before I accept your answer.

Glad to be of help!
